# Cosmos IO exception error in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cosmos

Hello guys I was recently using Cosomos to get Started in OS developemt , So I was using VS2010 and when I try to debug it, it gives some warning , and so I tried to debug it on VS2008 it debuged with no Waring and then it give me IO exception error keep in mind I never touched with single line of code, I've downloaded and installed created project and that was the first debug that had happened. all I'll provied some Images to be more clear
Edit: I've fixed by choosing QEMU Radiobtn but sometimes give the IO error and someother no !!
one more question why does it works only in VS2008 even all tutorails was made 
on vs2008 even the recent one [,First step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzY7U.png)[Here is the main exciption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5OYo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current versions of the Dev Kit and the User Kit require Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 or higher. Previous versions did work with older versions, and there was some (limited) support for express editions, but I believe those were dropped when the community version of visual studio was released without the limitations that express version imposed. If you pick up VS 2015 Community and install the latest updates you should be in working order.

From the FAQ:

> Why doesn't it work in VS [insert version number]?
>
> Latest versions only support VS2015. Older versions of Cosmos worked with VS2010 (including Express). Support skipped VS2012 and jumped to VS2013 (not including Express) and then to VS2015 (including Community Edition).

As to why it works partially in your older versions? I'm not entirely sure. .NET 3.5 is a required target, so VS 2008 is in scope, and you may have the required SDK components installed for it's requirements but it's certainly no longer supported by the dev team.